# Trouble with negating Core Data NSPredicate relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm scratching my head on this one. I have a work around, but I don't understand it so that doesn't count. What I want to do is for the entity (in this case a "Photo" lets say), I want to find all the Photos reviewed by anyone OTHER than the specified user. The relationship here is Photo->Review->User, where a photo can have multiple reviews, and each review is owned by exactly one user. The first two examples were my logical first attempts, but does not work. I found some similar code that shows the subquery which works, but can anyone explain why the first two examples don't work?

```
// this does not work
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (ANY reviews.user = %@)", self.user]

// this does not work
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE reviews.user = %@", self.user]

// this works
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(reviews, $x, $x.user == %@).@count == 0", self.user];
```

Comment: You can't use != in this situation: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Comment: You are correct, this won't work for a to-many, how is your entity model constructed such that reviews.user is a to-many relationship?

Comment: It should work (first and second examples). ImHuntingWabbits is probably on the right track, your model might be screwed up. Can you post a sample project or do you need one as an example?

Comment: I have the same issue, cannot negate relationships with NOT or NONE, only using a subquery.

Comment: I have this exact same problem - any fix??

Comment: You don't mention exactly what is wrong with the predicates, only that they "don't work".  When I try to reproduce, they are reproducing the behavior that I expect: https://github.com/drewcrawford/sotest
Can you fork the project with an assert that makes it clearer what is wrong?

Comment: @Duane Fields, how did you end up solving this? I have the exact same problem. None of the suggestions here work except for the subquery. How did you solve this? Or did you stick with the subquery?

Comment: I also have this problem, only subquery works.  I am trying to find all entities that have zero relationships with a certain value.  So NsPredicate(format: "NOT ANY relationshipToMany == %@", specificEntity) .  That doesn't work, gives back the same as without 'not' in the query.

Comment: Got the same issue. Looks like NOT ANY, ALL, or NONE doesn't work as expected in Core Data, not even the answer below with notPredicate on ANY. Only the subquery works.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY reviews.user = %@", self.user]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT reviews.user = %@", self.user]
```

Comment: NOT ANY or NOT ALL depending on the need

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you want to compare relationships in your predicate rather than attributes. Your `User` should have a unique attribute, such as `name`. I suggest that you use it in your predicate in the following way:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY comments.user.name != %@", @"John Smith"];
// NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE comments.user.name == %@", @"John Smith"];
request.predicate = p;
```

Answer (score -1):

I find it is better to perform Core Data relationship comparisons by comparing unique identifiers of the entity in question rather than the entity itself. For example, in my app I have an entity called `User`, which has an attribute `objectId`.  (Note: this is not to be confused with the internal `objectID` of the Core Data object. The `objectId` is simply a unique primary key from my external DB.  Then, your predicate would look like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"ANY reviews.user.objectId != %@", self.user.objectId];
```